# I need a Python script to output text from the clipboard when it is pasted there

Tags: python, windows, clipboard

I have code that displays the contents of a buffer without stopping. And I need to display this only when the buffer changes. Help friends

```
import win32clipboard
import threading
import time

def clipboard():
    while True:
        win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
        data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
        win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
        time.sleep(0.33)
        print(data)


clipboard = threading.Thread(target=clipboard)
clipboard.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified your `clipboard()` function. Hope this works.

```
import win32clipboard
import threading
import time

def clipboard():
    prev_data = None
    while True:
        win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
        data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
        win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
        time.sleep(0.33)

        if data != prev_data:
            print(data)
            prev_data = data


clipboard = threading.Thread(target=clipboard)
clipboard.start()
```